# How to get user UID when user is signed in with email in C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get the User's UID after the User is logged in successfully in C#.

I am trying to log in with command

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync()
```

and it is working nicely. But I want to get the UID of the user. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to get uid:

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth